# Javascript: How to count how much time a user spent watching a video?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe, video-reactjs

I am trying to save how much time a user spent watching video.
I stumbled upon the [played](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/buffering_seeking_time_ranges) video attribute:

> It’s worth mentioning the played property — this tells us which time
> ranges have been played within the media. For example:

```
var played = audio.played; // returns a TimeRanges object
```

> This could be useful for establishing the parts of your media that are
> most listened to or watched.

In my React app, I tried using that like this:

```
  handleStateChange(state, prevState) {
    const { played } = state;
    for (let index = 0; index < played.length; index++) {
      const beginning_of_played_segment = Math.trunc(played.start(index));
      const end_of_played_segment = Math.trunc(played.end(index));
    }
  }
```

`handleStateChanged` is used to subscribe to the video player state change:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.player && !this.state.hasSubscribedToPlayerState) {
      this.state.player.subscribeToStateChange(
        this.handleStateChange.bind(this)
      );
      this.setState({
        hasSubscribedToPlayerState: true,
      });
    }
  }
```

If I play the video between [0..8] and [347..357] secnds, the function `handleStateChange` logs something like this:

> ~ file: VideoItem.js ~ line 212 ~ VideoItem ~ handleStateChange ~
> beginning_of_play_segment 0
>
> ~ file: VideoItem.js ~ line 212 ~ VideoItem ~ handleStateChange ~
> end_of_play_segment 8
>
> ~ file: VideoItem.js ~ line 212 ~ VideoItem ~ handleStateChange ~
> beginning_of_play_segment 347
>
> ~ file: VideoItem.js ~ line 212 ~ VideoItem ~ handleStateChange ~
> end_of_play_segment 357

And then I thought I could just calculate the difference between all the `beginning_of_played_segment` and `end_of_played_segment` values.

The problem with this approach is that if I replay the video in a previously played segment, for example if I restart the video in the segment [0..8] in second 4, `played` will not create a new segment, and it will continue counting in that same segement.

For example, if I restart in 4, and continue playing until 13, the segment [0..8] will become [0..13].

This makes sense given that the `played` property ***tells us which time ranges have been played within the media.***

However, I would like to know if there's a property that would allow me to achieve my goal, of creating a new segment, everytime the user plays the video anywhere so that I can record how much time exactly he spent watching the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to implement a workaround. However, I am not sure this is the best approach. But, it works:

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      start_of_current_segment: 0,
      current_segment_duration: 0,
      segments: [],
      total_segments_duration: 0,
    };
   
  }

  handlePlayerStateChange(state, prevState) {
    const userHasJustPlayedVideo = prevState.paused && !state.paused;
    const userHasJustPausedVideo = !prevState.paused && state.paused;

    const { currentTime, seeking, hasStarted } = state;
    const has_user_moved_video_to_a_new_position = seeking;
    let { start_of_current_segment, segments } = this.state;
    if (userHasJustPlayedVideo) {
      segments = [...segments, 0];
      this.setState({
        start_of_current_segment: Math.trunc(currentTime),
        segments: segments,
      });
    } else if (userHasJustPausedVideo) {
    } else if (has_user_moved_video_to_a_new_position) {
      segments = [...segments, 0];
      this.setState({
        start_of_current_segment: Math.trunc(currentTime),
        segments: segments,
      });
    } else if (hasStarted) {
      const current_segment_duration =
        Math.trunc(currentTime) - start_of_current_segment;
      const segment_index = segments.length - 1;
      segments[segment_index] = current_segment_duration;

      let total_segments_duration = 0;
      for (
        let segment_index = 0;
        segment_index < segments.length;
        segment_index++
      ) {
        total_segments_duration += segments[segment_index];
      }

      this.setState({
        current_segment_duration: current_segment_duration,
        segments: segments,
        total_segments_duration: total_segments_duration,
      });

    }
  }
```